# Dot Net Nuke 5 calling webservice in module

Tags: web-services, dotnetnuke-5

this is very confusing for me, cannot picture how it can be done.  I have the following scenario:
I have a **server A** & **server B**, **Server A** hosts an application that saves in it information. **Server B** hosts a Dot Net Nuke website where the information should be displayed.

Now on **server A** web service resides and it converts the data to xml and is scheduled to run daily at a particular time.  On **server B** there are methods which reads the xml and import.

I need to expose the import method so that **server A** can use it.  It can be done by implementing a webservice residing in the same application pool, I want to package this webservice as a module which once installed will immediately create the virtual directory in the iis of the dot net nuke site and expose the needed methods.

**My concerns are the following:
Can I create a module to act as a webservice? 
or should I create a webservice and call it in the module?**

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use and package .ashx files in your DotNetNuke module. If you are creating a module to display the information that would be preferred over setting up it's own web service and putting it stand alone in IIS beside DNN.

You can then do whatever is necessary on Server A since it's not in DNN.

Comment: 10x for your answer.  In this module I don't want to display information. all I want is to have a webservice running on same IIS site due to some dnn settings (such as portal id, culture info etc..).  The scope of this module is to expose certain functionalities of other modules.

Comment: Yeah you can just add an .ashx file. Since modules are installed across an entire DNN installation and available to multiple portals on that install I think you would have to specify the portal, or pass some relevant ID's whenever accessing that web service. It's not going to just know what Portal you want.  But yeah, you can just use a .ashx file in your module. Or you could setup a full web service in IIS, but that would just depend on how sophisticated you expected your web service to get.